# Access UITableViewCell from UITableViewController on button click

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

Got a UIStepper inside a UITableViewCell (IBAction). What I would like is to reset its value property back to 0 from the UITableViewController on a button press (another IBAction).

So how can I access my dynamic cells from an a UITableViewController IBAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up adding a boolean property named shouldResetToZero in the model representing the cell. I would set this to TRUE from the UITableViewController on button press and update the stepper if it's true in cellForRowAtIndexPath.